# Why do we require that a toric variety have an action extending the torus action?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, toric-varieties

An **affine toric variety** is defined as a variety $X$ that contains a torus as an open dense subset *such that the natural action of torus on itself extends to an action on $X$*.

I would imagine that the torus action extends to all of $X$ just becuase the torus is embedded in $X$, but that portion of the definition always seems to be stated explicitly as a hypothesis. Are there examples of varieties $X$ that contain an embedded torus where the action *doesn't* extend? And what goes wrong in the usual construction of a cone from such a variety and torus embedding?

Comment: For a simple example, let $X$ be the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a torus non-invariant point on a torus-invariant line, such as $[0:1:1]$. The torus $(\Bbbk^*)^2 \subset X$ acts on the line $x=0$, transitively on $V(x) \setminus\{[0:0:1],[0:1:0]\}$. The action on $\mathbb{P}^2$ takes $[0:1:1]$ to all the points $[0:y:z]$ with $yz \neq 0$. It can't extend to the blowup $X$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thank you. Yeah, this works. Now this blowup $X$ is a projective toric variety, right? I'm trying to wiggle this into a similar affine example, but am having a bit of trouble. I think an affine example would make it easier to see what happens when you try to build the corresponding cone.